# Detach X11 app and reattach on another?

Tags: ssh, x11, x11forwarding

Given a setup of a headless Linux box running on a network, but having Xorg installed, and having various other machines on the network capable of using SSH with X-forwarding to connect to that box, and have X11 apps run on the local machine, I have an interesting question.

I'm familiar with using 'screen' to encapsulate an SSH session such that I can detach and reattach to it from a different machine, and while detached, processes continue to run, and when I reattach, I can scroll back through the buffer and see what was output.

Is the same thing possible for X11 apps? I ran into the situation where I wanted to run wireshark for some time to do some packet sniffing, but while it was running, I needed to switch computers, but realized there was no way that I knew to 'disconnect' from the wireshark thread, while still leaving it running, and in a state that I could reconnect to it at a later time (perhaps from a different machine) through another SSH session. Is there a similar process to the 'screen' disconnect/reconnect that can be done with X11 apps that are forwarded to a remote machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VNC will do this for you.  It's the Unix version of remote desktop.

Answer (score 14):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpra  sounds more like what you want to do than VNC..

Comment: Xpra looks like a clever utility, though I see it's not part of the Gentoo portage tree, so for my particular situation I'll go with VLC for now and try this in the future.

Comment: +1! I just set this up (well WinSwitch) on an Ubuntu server with an OS X client. It does exactly what I want!

Answer (score 3):

Other things that let you suspend and resume remote X sessions would include:

- Exceed onDemand (popular in the corporate / education worlds)
- NoMachine NX / the free wrapper for their GPL libraries, freeNX / Google's 'neatX' NX server

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [shifter](http://shifter.devloop.org.uk/)?