# ssh -X How to return a remote forwarded X application to localhost

Tags: ssh, x11, x11forwarding

I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.4
I'm opening an ssh session to a remote system running Ubuntu 10.0.4 Desktop

I open a remote VPN connection to a remote network
Then:
ssh -X user@host
screen -S openvas
sudo OpenVAS-Client #OpenVAS-Client GUI then forwards to my remote desktop

I want to configure and launch a scan in the OpenVAS GUI remotely over the ssh -X session. After I've launched the scan I want to send the OpenVAS-Client GUI back to its localhost, detach from my screen session, close the ssh session, and close the VPN connection. Hours later I want to be able to open the VPN connection again, ssh -X back into the remote computer, re-attach to the screen session, and bring the OpenVAS-Client back to my remote computer to look at the progress of the scan.

Is this possible?
Can someone point me in the direction of what commands and options to choose?

Thanks in advance.

Note: I don't really want to use VNC. I had installed NX and it worked in the lab but I can't log in over the VPN so that's a different problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detach X11 app and reattach on another?](http://serverfault.com/questions/102841/detach-x11-app-and-reattach-on-another)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Xpra](http://code.google.com/p/partiwm/wiki/xpra), it allows you to "detach" from and "reattach" to running X applications.

Comment: Try [this fork](http://xpra.org/), more up to date and less buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Also try [shifter](http://shifter.devloop.org.uk/). It's a little buggy, but I did manage to get it to work. I had a lot of trouble getting xpra to compile and run on OS X as a client - xpra is included as one of the methods of connecting to a remote machine in shifter (as well as NX and VNC).